# group name to change semantic highlighting in neovim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, neovim

TL;DR: I am looking for the correct group name to change semantic highlighting in neovim.
I'm using neovim (v0.8.3) together with `neoclide/coc`. I want to change the highlighting for variable in methods, for example:[image: in this attached screenshot.] You can see here that `actions` is highlighted in the body of the method because the cursor is on it right now. It's barely visible, though, and I would like to change the background color for this type of highlighting.
I assume the correct change in my config file is something like 
`:highlight [groupname] guibg=[somecolor]`
However, I have no idea what the correct group name is for this highlighting. The output of `:highlight` (listing all possible groups) is vast and I couldn't find it. 
This is my full list of plug-ins, if necessary:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'frazrepo/vim-rainbow'
Plug 'tanvirtin/monokai.nvim'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
" everything for telescope:
Plug 'jremmen/vim-ripgrep'
Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', { 'tag': '0.1.0' }
call plug#end()
```